# Properties get renamed when their name is the same as the datatype they return

Tags: c#, c++, com, com-interop, tlbexp

I am facing the following problem:

My interfaces are defined in C#. I use custom enums in my interfaces. Some of the enums have the same name as the datatype they return, e.g.:

```
Foo Foo { get; }
Bar Bar { get; }
```

I use tlbexp to use the module in C++.
Properties that share their name with their datatype are renamed from "Name" to "_Name":

> Bar myEnumValue = pFoo->Bar // does not exist
>
> Bar myEnumValue = pFoo->_Bar // is my 'Bar'-Property

So far, i did not find any documentation about the reason and if/how i am able to prevent this.
I do not get any warnings during build or export..
To make the usage of my module intuitive, I do not want to rename the property or the enum.

Can anyone explain me why this happens?

Comment: Not being a C++ expert, I'm guessing this has something to do with the [Color color](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/06/color-color.aspx) problem and the way C++ handles (not) it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ this is not allowed:

```
class B {};
class A {
    B B;
};
```

because of `[basic.scope.class] 3.3.7/1`:

> A name N used in a class S shall refer to the same declaration in its context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of S. No diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.

---

Note that this applies only to declarations inside a class, for namespace scope or function scope the rules are more complicated - sometimes `B B;` is allowed, sometimes not.

---

**Update**: actually this is perfectly valid:

```
class B {};
class A {
    ::B B;
};
```

So you can try to make `tlbexp` generate code like this.

Comment: thank you for providing the reason.. do you have any idea how i can prevent this? with your given information, i have read that i could e.g. specify a scope to prevent the error.. can i tell tlbexp to do so?

Comment: What do you want to prevent? Again, there's no way to get `Foo Foo;` in a C++ class. You cannot "specify a scope" - a class member has the scope of its class. Maybe you can play with [tlbexp options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfzzah2c(v=vs.110).aspx) to get some different naming for such properties.

Comment: i think i got something wrong in the post i referred to. Thank you very much for your answer!